# Angular 11 - ngFor is not working in incrementing index

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, ngfor

I want to use the indexNumArr as the incrementing index of row.quiz_records[]..., but I can't seem to make it work. I'm really having a hard time thinking what is wrong, because I think that the logic is right.

html

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceQuizOverview" matSort>
    
    <ng-container *ngFor="let index of indexNumArr">
              <ng-container matColumnDef="question_text">
                <th class="font" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Questions</th>
                <td class="font" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.quiz_records[{{index}}].question_text}}</td>
              </ng-container>
         
      
              <ng-container matColumnDef="user_answers">
                <th class="font" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Answer</th>
                <td class="font" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.quiz_records[{{index}}].user_answers}}</td>
              </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    
    </table>
```

ts

```
 indexNumArr: number [] = [0, 1];
```

array response

```
"quizRemarks": [
        {
            "id": 160,
            "user_id": 1,
            "quiz_id": 18,
            "module_id": 29,
            "number_of_correct_answers": 2,
            "created_at": "2021-10-15T03:52:52.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-10-15T03:52:52.000000Z",
            "time_started": null,
            "time_finished": null,
            "remarks": 1,
            "quiz_records": [
                {
                    "id": 27,
                    "user_scores_id": 160,
                    "question_id": 2,
                    "user_answers": "DriverPH",
                    "remarks_correct_incorrect": "1",
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": null,
                    "question_text": "What is the name of this application?"
                },
                {
                    "id": 28,
                    "user_scores_id": 160,
                    "question_id": 2,
                    "user_answers": "Red",
                    "remarks_correct_incorrect": "1",
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": null,
                    "question_text": "What traffic light color tells you to stop before the intersection?"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: set this "row.quiz_records[index].user_answers"

Comment: It is error again

Comment: Did you forget a double quote at the end `*ngFor="let index of indexNumArr">`?

Comment: It's much more helpful to tell us what error.

Comment: So what is the error? Also, yes, nesting `{{ }}` is wrong. A single block will already bring you into 'interpolation realm'.

Comment: No, it's just a typo @Pieterjan

Comment: Are there any workaround for this? @GunnarB.

Comment: This is the error, error NG5002: Parser Error: Missing expected : at the end of the expression [{{row.quiz_records[{{index}}].question_text}}] @Phix

Comment: You don't need nested `{{}}` if that is what you are asking for by workaround. Removing the inner pair of {{}} will do what you want. `{{ ... }}` is saying 'everything between is typescript'. By nesting them you basically say 'I want to access typescript inside typescript inside html'.

Comment: Perhaps the name `index` causes a conflict. `index` is pre-defined in your `*ngFor` and should probably get another name

Comment: I tried other name, it's not working. @Pieterjan

Comment: I tried removing the {{}} it also not working. @GunnarB.

Comment: So, what is the error you are getting now?